# Use Google Gears geolocation from a python app

Tags: geolocation, gears

I'd like to use the Google geolocation API in my app, written in Python. My problem is that Google provides a JSON interface (easily useable from Python) but from http://code.google.com/p/gears/wiki/GeolocationAPI I see that the API "is published to allow developers to provide their own network location server for use through the Gears API. Google's network location server is only to be used through the Gears API. See section 5.3 of the Gears Terms of Service at *[address]*."

It is a very strange thing: there is a very cool JSON but I cannot use it. I have to use it through Google Gears instead. But how can I do it from a Python app?

For example, I see that the geolocation service provided by Firefox calls directly the JSON API. Why is FF able to do that?

Thanks,
Alessio Palmero Aprosio

Comment: Firefox and google have an agreement which lets them use the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has [deprecated Gears entirely](http://gearsblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/hello-html5.html), as the geolocation feature is now [standard in modern browsers](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) (for certain values of "standard").

The [pylocation](https://github.com/mcos/pylocation) module may provide the information you need.  It can output the geolocation data in text, json, or xml.

Comment: i think pylocation does only IP based geolocation and not wifi-mac-address based geolocation that FF does .